# component doesn't update after state update

Tags: reactjs

the following code doesn't update my component.

the state is updated with another function. so I'd assume the component would update aswell.

Entire Class is here.

```
class QuestionList extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            questions : []          
        }
        this.childHandler = this.childHandler.bind(this);
    }

    updateData()
    {
        const get = '/application/questions/'
        api.get(get)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({questions : response.data});
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        var tempArray = [];
        const get = '/application/questions/'
        api.get(get)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({questions : response.data});
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    childHandler( update )
    {
        const {questions} = this.state;
        let tempQs = questions;
        const length = questions.length;
        var temp = [];
        var temp1 = [];

        console.log ( tempQs );
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if(questions[i].q_id == update[1])//find New
            {
                temp = [questions[i].q_id,questions[i].question];
                for(var x = 0; x < length; x++)//find old
                {
                    
                    if(questions[x].q_id == update[0] && questions[x].q_id != questions[i].q_id ) 
                    {
                        temp1 = [questions[x].q_id,questions[x].question];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
                
             
            }
        }       
        tempQs[temp[0]-1].question = temp1[1];
        tempQs[temp1[0]-1].question = temp[1];
        this.setState({questions : tempQs},console.log(questions));
    }

    render()
    {
        var { questions } = this.state;
        console.log(questions);
        var qs;
        qs = questions.map(val => {
            return(
                <QuestionCards q_id={val.q_id} max={questions.length} action={this.childHandler}>{val.question}</QuestionCards>
            )
        });

        return(
            <Table hover>
                <tbody>
                        <tr className="title">
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Question</th>
                            <td colspan="3" ><Button color="primary">Add Question</Button></td>
                        </tr>
                    {qs}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        );
    }
}
```

here is the cards component

```
class QuestionCards extends Component
{
    constructor ( props )
    {
        super(props)
            this.state = {
                fireModal : false,
                modal : false,
                q_id : this.props.q_id,
                question : this.props.children,
                max : this.props.max
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleModal = this.handleModal.bind(this);
        this.triggerModal = this.triggerModal.bind(this);
        this.moveUp = this.moveUp.bind(this);
        this.moveDown = this.moveDown.bind(this);
    }
   
    triggerModal ( trig )
    {
        const {q_id} = this.state;
        if (trig)
            return (
                <QListModal q_id={q_id} trigger={trig} action={this.childHandler}/>
            );
    }

    handleModal ( val )
    {
        const { fireModal } = this.state;
        console.log('fireModel: ' + fireModal)
        if( !fireModal )
        {
            this.setState({
                mTarget : val,
                fireModal : true   ,
                update : []
            });
        }
        else
        {
            this.setState({fireModal:false})
        }
        
    }

    moveUp ()
    {
        var tempArray = [];
        const { q_id } = this.state;
        const dir = 'up';
        const get = '/application/move/' + q_id +'/'+ dir;
        api.get(get).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.setState({
                update : [res.data.newId,res.data.oldId]
            })
            return this.props.action(this.state.update);
        });
        //return this.props.action(this.state.update);
    }

    moveDown ()
    {
        var tempArray = [];
        const { q_id } = this.state;
        const dir = 'down';
        const get = '/application/move/' + q_id +'/'+ dir;
        api.get(get).then(res => {
            this.setState({
                update : [res.data.newId,res.data.oldId]})
            return this.props.action(this.state.update);
        });
        //return this.props.action();
    }

    render()
    {
        const {
            fireModal,
            q_id,
            question,
            max,
            update
        } = this.state

        let ButtonUp;
        let ButtonDown;
        if( q_id <= 1)
        {
            ButtonUp = <td></td>
        }
        else
        {
            ButtonUp = <td><Button id={q_id} onClick={this.moveUp}>▲</Button></td>
        }
        if( q_id == max)
        {
            ButtonDown = <td></td>
        }
        else
        {
            ButtonDown = <td><Button id={q_id} onClick={this.moveDown}>▼</Button></td>
        }
        return(
            <tr>
                <th>{q_id}</th>
                <td>{question}</td>
                <td><Button onClick={this.handleModal}>Edit</Button></td>
                {ButtonUp}
                {ButtonDown}
                {this.triggerModal(fireModal)}
            </tr>
            

        )
    }
}
```

```
    render()
    {
        var { questions } = this.state;

        var qs = questions.map(val => {
            return(
                <QuestionCards q_id={val.q_id} max={questions.length} action={this.childHandler}>{val.question}</QuestionCards>
            )
        });

        return(
            <Table hover>
                <tbody>
                    {qs}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        );
    }
}
```

what the app is trying to do is every time the up or down arrow is pressed. it updates it on the page.

For some reason after updating the state it doesn't update the output itself.

though when i console.log the state it self it is updated.

this is my first independent project I'm still learning React/Javascript as a whole.

as you can see the state updates properly. but just doesn't re render anything.
the profiler tool in react-dev-tools outputs nothing rendered. could it be because of the parent component?

**Solution**
My problem was with the constructor for question cards.

```
 super(props)
            this.state = {
                fireModal : false,
                modal : false,
                q_id : this.props.q_id,
                question : this.props.children, // This line in particular
                max : this.props.max
        }
```

I wasn't updating the state with the new Info.
so i just assign the value of `this.props.children` to a constant in the render function

this is the updated render for `QuestionCards`

```
    render()
    {
        const {
            fireModal,
            q_id,
            max
        } = this.state

        const question = this.props.children;
        let ButtonUp;
        let ButtonDown;
        if( q_id <= 1)
        {
            ButtonUp = <td></td>
        }
        else
        {
            ButtonUp = <td><Button id={q_id} onClick={this.moveUp}>▲</Button></td>
        }
        if( q_id == max)
        {
            ButtonDown = <td></td>
        }
        else
        {
            ButtonDown = <td><Button id={q_id} onClick={this.moveDown}>▼</Button></td>
        }
        return(
            <tr>
                <th>{q_id}</th>
                <td>{question}</td>
                <td><Button onClick={this.handleModal}>Edit</Button></td>
                {ButtonUp}
                {ButtonDown}
                {this.triggerModal(fireModal)}
            </tr>
            

        )
    }
```

also removed the console logs to declutter the post!

Thank you all for helping me trouble shoot!

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. What, where, and how is state being updated?

Comment: what does Add Question Button do? Can you add more code?

Comment: updated the post with more detail and more code

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

Looks like a state mutation in `cardHandler`

```
childHandler( update ) {
    const {questions} = this.state;
    let tempQs = questions; // <-- saved current state ref to tempQs
    
    ...

    tempQs[temp[0]-1].question = temp1[1]; // <-- mutated state ref
    tempQs[temp1[0]-1].question = temp[1];  // <-- mutated state ref
    this.setState({questions : tempQs},console.log(questions)); // <-- saved state ref
}
```

## Solution

Shallow copy `questions` into *new* array reference to update. This should allow react's state/props reference test to detect that state is a new object and rerender.

```
const {questions} = this.state;
let tempQs = [...questions]; // <-- spread existing array into new array
```

Comment: should i be doing anything else to my code?  doing the edit didn't have the required effect.

Comment: @RandomBash Perhaps there are further issues. What is `this.childHandler` in `QuestionCards`? Can you varify/validate (using the react-dev-tools in browser) that state *is actually* updating? Provide any other debugging details? Are you able to post up a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue and provide a set of reproduction steps?

Comment: Looks like `temp` and `temp1` should hold `i +1` and `x + 1` as their first elements. Consider using `Array.find()` or `Array.findIndex()` instead of your loops.

Please add some samples of `questions` and data returned by `/application/move/...`.

Comment: @UjinT34, i've tried different was to swapping the state data. one is even reloading the data from the data base. and reseting it that way. still didn't work.

Comment: @DrewReese i downloaded react-dev-tools and I used the profiler and it says nothing "rendered" but the state updates properly

Comment: @RandomBash Please try to get a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) of your code and update with a link in your question. It may be easier to debug than playing 20 questions.

Comment: @DrewReese i figured it out. Updated post in what caused it.